# Programatically obtaining the AWS ES endpoint when in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch domain in AWS inside a VPC and I need to execute some REST requests against it (my network is set up in such a way that I can do that).

To that end, I would like to ask you guys if there is a way to obtain the Elasticsearch endpoint programatically? I mean, the value of the "VPC endpoint" field in this screen shot [image: screen shot] for example, but through an AWS CLI or API call rather than through the UI.

`aws es describe-elasticsearch-domain` does not apply, as my domain is inside a vpc.

I have had some success with obtaining the IP address of the network interface, with this command:
`aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters "Name=status,Values=in-use" "Name=description,Values=ES my-es-domain-name" --query "NetworkInterfaces[*].PrivateIpAddress"` but it doesn't work with the REST calls (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException).

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: *"`aws es describe-elasticsearch-domain` does not apply, as my domain is inside a vpc."*  How does that make it not apply?

Comment: Well I tried the command and I got back a null endpoint field. Trying to figure out why it was null, I found a number of sources on the internet, such as this one: https://www.cloudconformity.com/conformity-rules/Elasticsearch/domain-in-vpc.html, which basically say that you get null when domain is inside vpc. Quote from link: "The command output should return the requested endpoint URL or null if the selected ES domain is currently associated with a VPC".

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it looks like I was using an older version of the java sdk, as well as aws cli.

I updated my aws cli and, in the same scenario, with version 1.15.31 of the cli, `aws es describe-elasticsearch-domain` returns a field called `Endpoints`, which contains the endpoint.

I was able to obtain the same result with version 1.11.328 of the java sdk (`com.amazonaws.services.elasticsearch.AWSElasticsearch.describeElasticsearchDomain.getDomainStatus`). Indeed `DescribeElasticsearchDomainResult.getEndpoint` returns null, but in this version there's also a `DescribeElasticsearchDomainResult.getEndpoints` method, which returns a map containing the endpoint.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, the endpionts are just missing from the JSON returned by awscli :(

Comment: If the endpoints are missing from the awscli output then try upgrading the boto3 library: `pip install --user boto3`.